# How do I access a component variable in an angular (click) string

Tags: angular

I am using mat-table-exporter in a component. I am using a button to active the export like the example shows to do. However in the (click) string I want to access a variable of the component but can't figure out how to do it (if it is possible). Here is the particular button definition with viewName being the variable I want to use:

```
      (click)="exporter.exportTable('xlsx', {fileName:'{{viewName}}'})">Excel</button>
```

Comment: Just drop the moustaches and the quotes around `viewName`

Comment: Wow that is it! I knew it would be something simple like that.

Comment: To give more explanation: what you write in the click handler is just regular JavaScript. Write it like you would if you were in the JS/TS file.

Answer (score 0):

Add a method in the component and use the methode in the (click)

Comment: How would I access that referenced component within the component code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.

```
    <input #fileName />

    (click)="exporter.exportTable('xlsx', {fileName:fileName.value})">Excel</button>
```

Hope this helps.